# creating dataframe from nested dictionary using python

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

The following is the json data available to me

```
{
  "status": "success",
  "message": "Transactions Details",
  "TxnArray": [    
    {
      "transactionAmount": {"0": 3500},
      "createdAt": {"0": "17/04/2020"}
    },    
    {
      "transactionAmount": {"1": 4500},
      "createdAt": {"1": "19/04/2020"}
    }
  ]
}
```

Want to convert the above data in pandas `Dataframe` like

```
      transactionAmount createdAt
    0 3500               17/4/2020
    1 4500               19/4/2020
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A slightly different yet compact approach,

```
pd.concat(pd.DataFrame.from_dict(d) for d in data['TxnArray'])
```

Answer (score 1):

A more compact approach:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([
    {k: v[str(i)] for k, v in list_item.items()} for i, list_item in enumerate(json_data['TxnArray'])
])
```

Comment: That was really helpful and compact solution. Thank you so much..

Comment: I am getting started with all this. Could you help me what  "_" is used for? It would be a great help.

Comment: you have a point @PriteshChoksi . `_` is not human friendly. I edited my answer in order to increase readability. So... `_` was every list's item

Answer (score 0):

```py
import pandas as pd
import json

json_str = json.loads('''{
  "status": "success",
  "message": "Transactions Details",
  "TxnArray": [    
    {
      "transactionAmount": {"0": 3500},
      "createdAt": {"0": "17/04/2020"}
    },    
    {
      "transactionAmount": {"1": 4500},
      "createdAt": {"1": "19/04/2020"}
    }
  ]
}''')

df = pd.DataFrame(json_str['TxnArray'])
```

[image]

```py
def clean_function(x):
    return list(x.values())[0]

df = df.applymap(lambda x: clean_function(x))
```

[image]